# How to join column with a column that has a same name in sql?

Tags: mysql

How to join all group and create auto generated `newcolumn` column where file name is same?

```
File Name |  Group
----------+---------
 Log.csv  |  1001
 Log.csv  |  1000
 Log.csv  |  1005
 blue.txt |  1001
 blue.txt |  1005
```

Expected result:

```
File Name |  Group  | NewColumn
----------+---------+---------------
 Log.csv  |  1001   | 1001,1000,1005 
 Log.csv  |  1000   | 1001,1000,1005
 Log.csv  |  1005   | 1001,1000,1005
 Log.csv  |  1001   | 1001,1005
 Log.csv  |  1005   | 1001,1005
```

Comment: what db are you using?

Comment: XAMPP is not a SQL engine.  What is your database vendor (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?

Comment: Oh sorry sir im kinda newbie. I am using mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8+ or a recent version of MariaDB, then you may use `GROUP_CONCAT` here as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT file_name, GROUP_CONCAT(`Group`) OVER (PARTITION BY file_name) AS NewColumn
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY file_name, `Group`;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL/MariaDB, we might have to join with a subquery as an alternative:

```sql
SELECT t1.file_name, t2.NewColumn
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT file_name, GROUP_CONCAT(`Group`) AS NewColumn
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY file_name
) t2
    ON t2.file_name = t1.file_name
ORDER BY
    t1.file_name,
    t1.`Group`;
```

Comment: Hello! The second one worked for me. I'm probably using a earlier version of my sql.

Comment: Sir can I ask for additional help? Same question but different result.

Comment: You may want to open a new question if not directly related to what you already asked (and what was answered) here.

Comment: Okay sir i'll just post another question. Thank you :)